# Why is GLS often used with RMLE?

Tags: regression

I am trying to learn about how different parameters in mixed effects regression models are estimated.

For the following model:

$$y = X\beta + Zb + \epsilon$$

I read that a popular approach first involves estimating the fixed effects using GLS:

$$Q(\beta) = (y - X\beta)'V^{-1}(y - X\beta)$$
$$\frac{\partial Q(\beta)}{\partial \beta} = -2X'V^{-1}(y - X\beta) = 0$$
$$X'V^{-1}X\beta = X'V^{-1}y$$
$$\hat{\beta}_{GLS} = (X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}y$$

From here, we sub in the GLS estimates into the original likelihood and estimate the mixed effects:

$$y = X\hat{\beta}_{GLS} + Zb + \epsilon$$

When we write the modified likelihood after subbing in the GLS estimates, it looks like:

$$L(\beta, b, \sigma^2 | y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi\sigma^2)^n |V|}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (y - X\beta - Zb)'V^{-1}(y - X\beta - Zb)\right)$$

where $V = Z\sigma_b^2Z' + \sigma^2I$ is the variance-covariance matrix of the response vector $y$.

Since the conditional response is multivariate normal - we can write the following equations and solve for the parameters of interest:

$$L(\hat{\beta}_{\text{GLS}}, b, \sigma^2 | y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi\sigma^2)^n \lvert V \rvert}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (y - X\hat{\beta}_{\text{GLS}} - Zb)'V^{-1}(y - X\hat{\beta}_{\text{GLS}} - Zb)\right)$$

I am trying to understand : Why is the RMLE procedure set up like this? Intuitively, I can accept the argument that GLS provides unbiased estimates of the fixed effects and then the estimates of the mixed effects will be unbiased when based on a likelihood with GLS fixed effects.

Is the correct gist of things?